# How to contain only reference to objects in NSMutableArray?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

Let's say we have a NSMutableArray (or NSMutableDictionary) that has data from the same type "Class1".

I want to create a new NSMutableArray (or NSMutableDictionary) with only half of the data from the first one.

What I want is in the second mutable object I have created to only have references to the already existing objects not to "copy" them.

For example if I change some property's value of one of the objects in the first mutable object to have the change in the second mutable object at once.

For example:

Let's say I have an NSMutableArray of objects of type Person called people I have 3 properties in the Person class:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Gender

Now I want to have my second NSMutableArray (women) have only the "female" Person objects from people. I change the name of one woman in the people object and then when I print all the objects from the women object her name should be printed out with the new data that I just changed in the people object.

If the name was "XXX" in both arrays, when I change it in the first to "YYY" and print out the values of the second where it should have said "XXX" now it should say "YYY" instead.

Comment: That's how it already works. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Apparently none. :D I'm coming from .NET. How about properties that are IBOutlets?

Comment: `IBOutlet` is an empty decoration used to allow Interface Builder to know what things you'd like to be able to connect to (see `NSNibDeclarations.h` and `UINibDeclarations.h`). It has no compile-time or run-time influence on your code. That said, I can't think of a case where you would have an `NSMutableArray` that was also an `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how all `NSMutableArray` objects work. ObjC very seldom makes copies of objects when putting them into collections (the keys to dictionaries being the major exception).

Comment: I've been using NSDictionary for years and had no idea that it copies the keys, good think I've only ever used short NSString for them I guess